# Any idea on how to achieve this effect without GLSL

Tags: java, libgdx, glsl, shader, effect

Do you have any idea how this 2D effect could be done any other way than using GLSL shader? Such a glowing effect, could be done with textures, but then how to do such a dynamic bubble around them?

In this case, each object in the bubble goes to some destination. Then their positions I send to the vertex shader and then to fragment shader. In fragment shader there will be some calculations to achieve this effect. I draw shader on background texture of size 1280x720.

The problem is that it is very slow. I originally wanted to use it on mobile phones, but i think it is without chance. A further problem is that from the vertex to fragment i can not send a lot of positions (in this case 30 positions). When shader compile with more positions it reports "Not enough space for Defined varyings".
To render I use Libgdx framework.

Any help is welcome. Even for achieving a similar effect.
I attach the picture here on how it should look like. And shader code.

[image: glowy dots]

Vertex:

```
attribute vec4 a_position;
uniform mat4 u_worldView;
uniform float u_xPos[30];
uniform float u_yPos[30];
uniform float u_size;

varying float xPos[30];
varying float yPos[30];
varying float size;
void main()
{
    gl_Position = u_worldView * a_position;
    size = u_size;

    int NN = int(u_size);

    for(int i=0; i<NN; ++i){
    xPos[i] = u_xPos[i];
    yPos[i] = u_yPos[i];
}
```

Fragment:

```
varying float xPos[30];
varying float yPos[30];
varying float size;

void main( void ) {
    float rad = 4.0;
    float dist = 0.0;
    vec2 pos = vec2(0.0,0.0);
    vec3 color = vec3(0.1);
    vec2 pixel = gl_FragCoord.xy;
    vec3 c = vec3(0.53, 0.05, 0.1);

    float xx[30]= xPos;
    float yy[30]= yPos;

    int NN = int(size);
    for(int i=0; i<NN; ++i){
        pos = vec2(xx[i] , yy[i]) - pixel;
        dist += rad / length(pos);
    }

    color = c.yzx*dist;
    gl_FragColor = vec4(color, 1.0);
}
```

Comment: Maybe draw all the particles in their same relative positions, but as very blurry, dark gray, large circle sprites onto a low resolution (quarter the dimensions of the screen) frame buffer object, additively. Draw the frame buffer texture fullscreen with linear mag function. The brightness of the pixels is basically your `dist` parameter, so you don't have to handle particle or screen positions in your shader at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without GLSL that will be very tricky, but if the problem is that it's too slow perhaps the following approach helps:

1. Render a large white blurred circle (premade) additively for each spark

   - Optionally apply a blur shader to make it more smooth, might not be needed
2. Use result as a mask, render blue hues depending on the value

   - dark-gray to gray becomes dark-blue to bright-blue
   - gray to white becomes bright-blue to saturated-blue
3. Render each spark additively on top

Comment: Thanks, I achieved almost same result. But I did not use "mask". I just played with blurred circle textures (colors, alphas). And i used lower dimension for framebuffer by Tenfour04 answer.